# Can someone explain the intuition of loops when used on dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, logic

I want to fully understand what each line of code does as I am currently not 100% sure. The code is from a tutorial series I am watching from PythonProgramming.net.

I believe the first 'If' statement is adding columns to the act_min_wage dataframe and then renaming them?

The 'else' statement seems to be joining the index to the new dataframe, act_min_wage? Is this what is happening?

Why do we need the first if statement? Would not the second one to just join them suffice?

Thanks so much for your help.

```
act_min_wage = pd.DataFrame()

for name, group in df.groupby("State"):
    if act_min_wage.empty:
        act_min_wage = group.set_index("Year")[["Low.2018"]].rename(columns={"Low.2018":name})
    else:
        act_min_wage = act_min_wage.join(group.set_index("Year")[["Low.2018"]].rename(columns={"Low.2018":name}))

act_min_wage.head()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) `act_min_wage = pd.DataFrame()`

creates empty DataFrame

2) `for name, group in df.groupby("State"):`

*df.groupby("State")* - group dataframe by column *"State"*, so in the loop
*name* - unique values of column *"State"*
*group* - all rows from *df* that have value of column *"State"* equal to current *name*

3)

```
 if act_min_wage.empty:
        act_min_wage = group.set_index("Year")[["Low.2018"]].rename(columns={"Low.2018":name})
```

If new dataframe *act_min_wage* is empty (only on first iteration) put there *group* and rename column  *"Low.2018"*  to *name* (unique values of column *"State"* of *df*)

4)

```
    else:
        act_min_wage = act_min_wage.join(group.set_index("Year")[["Low.2018"]].rename(columns={"Low.2018":name}))
```

As *act_min_wage* is not empty, join it with new *group* based on *Year* values, on default it is left joining.

So if statement was used to replace empty dataframe by *group* with index *"Year"*.

Comment: Thank you for such a comprehensive explanation, it has really clarified this for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code with a toy example to understand all steps better:

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display, HTML

df = pd.DataFrame({'State': ['NY', 'NY', 'C', 'C', 'W'], 
                   'Low.2018': [0, 5, 10, 2, 3], 
                   'Year': [2017, 2018, 2017, 2018, 2017]})

act_min_wage = pd.DataFrame()

for name, group in df.groupby("State"):
    print('NEW ITERATION', '\n', 'Group:', '\n', '\t', name)
    display(group)
    print('\n', 'Current state of act_min_wage')
    display(act_min_wage)
    print('\n\n')
    if act_min_wage.empty:
        act_min_wage = group.set_index("Year")[["Low.2018"]].rename(columns={"Low.2018":name})
    else:
        act_min_wage = act_min_wage.join(group.set_index("Year")[["Low.2018"]].rename(columns={"Low.2018":name}))

print('\n', 'Final state of act_min_wage')
display(act_min_wage)
```